# InputBuffer in Jackson parser

Tags: java, json, jackson

I use Jackson for parsing JSON files. The file is passed as a stream to Jackson to create a parser. Here is the sample code :

```
JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser parser = f.createParser(inputStream);
```

I know that createParser() prefetch data from stream into an input buffer. Subsequent call to nextToken() is served from this inputBuffer. In my application, along with parsing, I also want to keep track of the file offset of the inputStream until which I have consumed the data. Due to this buffering, offset tracking does not work.

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable buffering in Jackson? Or, is there an API call that I can use to determine if the buffer has data that has not yet been consumed?

Comment: You could always pass a InputStream to the parser which wraps the original InputStream and keeps track of the consumed bytes

Comment: @wero : Thanks for your answer. Not sure how wrapping original inputStream would work. Once the parser buffers the data, I need to know if we have data in the buffer that will get consumed in subsequent getNextToken() call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `JsonParser.getTokenLocation()` or  `JsonParser.getCurrentLocation()` to keep track of the file offset?

The returned object seems to have the byte position (in addition to the character position), which should be to position in the underlying input stream...

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#getCurrentLocation()

Comment: Actually getTokenLocation() is the thing I need. Thanks for your answer.